# Read line by line from an updating log file in real time

Tags: php, logging, real-time

I have a log file from which I am writing the data to a php file. This is the code for that:

```
$filename='/var/log/siawa/dashboard/iot.log';

$source_file = fopen( $filename, "r" ) or die("Couldn't open $filename");

while (!feof($source_file)) {
    $buffer = fgets($source_file, 4096);  // use a buffer of 4KB
    $buffer = str_replace($old,$new,$buffer);
    echo $buffer. "<br />" . "\n";
}
```

This is working but i want to update the php log data after say every 10 seconds once its gets written in the original log file. How to do that.

Answer (score 3):

You need to read the file contents in an infinite `while(true)` loop. I'll explain through code comments.

```
// read.php
<?php

// Last read position
$last = 0;

// Path to the updating log file
$file = 'log.txt';

while (true) {
    // PHP caches file information in order to provide faster
    // performance; In order to read the new filesize, we need
    // to flush this cache.
    clearstatcache(false, $file);

    // Get the current size of file
    $current = filesize($file);

    // Reseted the file?
    if ($current < $last) {
        $last = $current;
    }
    // If there's new content in the file
    elseif ($current > $last) {
        // Open the file in read mode
        $fp = fopen($file, 'r');

        // Set the file position indicator to the last position
        fseek($fp, $last);

        // While not reached the end of the file
        while (! feof($fp)) {
            // Read a line and print
            print fgets($fp);
        }

        // Store the current position of the file for the next pass
        $last = ftell($fp);

        // Close the file pointer
        fclose($fp);
    }
}
```

To test this, open a terminal window and issue:

```
while true; do echo `date` >> log.txt; sleep 1; done
```

This will append the current datetime string to the file for each single second. Now open another terminal and issue `php read.php` to see if the file is being read in real-time. It will output something like this:

```
Wed Dec 28 18:01:12 IRST 2016
Wed Dec 28 18:01:13 IRST 2016
Wed Dec 28 18:01:14 IRST 2016
Wed Dec 28 18:01:15 IRST 2016
Wed Dec 28 18:01:16 IRST 2016
Wed Dec 28 18:01:17 IRST 2016
Wed Dec 28 18:01:18 IRST 2016
# Keeps updating...
```

If you tend to serve this over HTTP, you'll need to add a [`ob_flush()`](https://php.net/ob_flush) call after printing the read buffer:

```
// While not reached the end of the file
 while (! feof($fp)) {
     print fgets($fp) . '<br>';

     // Flush the output cache
     ob_flush();
 }
```